# Etymology of "bizarre"?

Tags: etymology, italian

> *bizarre* n. "very strange or unusual"

I know that it (likely) comes from Basque. Does anyone have a certain knowledge of this? I heard that it comes from Italian from some sources, too.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bizarre&searchmode=none

Comment: @Jim No, that is not a sufficient reference. In fact, it’s a very bad one. This should not be closed as GR, because it clearly is not!  The Basque theory is pretty thoroughly trounced.

Comment: @tchrist- While it certainly does not contain as much detail as you have provided the result is the same.  OED *et al* provide the same French, Basque, Italian traces and mentions *alternative etymologies* which, in my mind, means *they don't know for sure* so I wouldn't count this as a *Very Bad One* just maybe not as in depth as yours.

Comment: I didn't close-vote the question for the sake of tchrist's answer but this question could be presented better. You gave a hint that you made some research but you didn't include any details or sources. We encourage that you include all the research you have done. Please check: [How much research is neededd?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)

Comment: ["*Moi, j'ai dit bizarre ? Comme c'est bizarre.*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ku-ChVdBwDs)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TLDR**: Not Basque but Italian, but beyond that, we don’t know.

---

The OED reports Littré’s Basque ([Euskera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basque_language)) theory, but does not quite seem to believe it (bold emphasis mine):

> **Etymology**: mod.Eng. (17th c.), a. Fr. *bizarre* ‘odd, fantastic,’ formerly ‘brave, soldier-like’; cf. Sp. and Pg. *bizarro* ‘handsome, brave,’ Ital. *bizzarro* ‘angry, choleric,’ dial. Fr. (Berry) *bigearrer* to quarrel. Littré suggests that the Spanish word is an adaptation of Basque *bizarra* beard, in the same manner as *hombre de bigote* moustached man, is used in Sp. for a ‘man of spirit’; **but the history of the sense has not been satisfactorily made out.**
>
> - 1667 Evelyn *Mem*. (1857) III. 161 We have hardly any words that do so fully express the French··*naivete, ennui, bizarre, concert··emotion, defer, effort*··let us therefore (as the Romans did the Greek) make as many of these do homage as are like to prove good citizens.

Of [the Spanish, the RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=bizarro) says only that it comes from the Italian *bizzarro* which it glosses as having meant anger-prone in that language. They do point out in their [*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=bizarro) that the Spanish word only means “valiant”, not “strange” or “extravagant” like the French or English sense of the word, which it calls a “censurable semantic calque” in Spanish. However, the truth is that it is more and more getting used that way, which perhaps is why they complain. :)

Meanwhile, if you [look in Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/bizarre), you find this:

> #### ÉTYMOLOGIE
>
> Berry, bigearre ; bigearrer, disputer ; espagn. et portug. bizarro, magnanime, vaillant ; ital. bizarro, emporté, colère. Notre mot français vient de l'espagnol et il a eu d'abord le sens de vaillant, brave (voy. à l'historique l'exemple de Lanoue). L'italien a, il est vrai, un substantif bizza, colère ; mais bizarro n'en peut dériver, puisque le suffixe arr n'est pas italien. Tout porte à croire que le mot est d'origine espagnole ; dès lors deux étymologies s'offrent : le basque bizarra, barbe, décomposé par Larramendi en biz arra (qu'il soit un homme) ; et l'arabe basharet, beauté, élégance, d'où vaillant, chevaleresque, puis les sens de colère, emporté, extravagant.

Which claims that the French word comes from Spanish, but that there are two competing theories, one from Basque and the other from Arabic.  The Basque theory it traces to *biz arra* for subjunctive “[that one/he] be a man” in Basque. For the Arabic theory it tries to connect Arabic *basharet* related to elegance and thence to valiance and once again towards high-spirited.

An article on [About World Languages](http://aboutworldlanguages.com/basque) just echoes the common bearded theory:

> from French *bizarre* ‘odd, strange’, possibly from Basque *bizar* ‘beard’ (possibly due tof the strange impression made in France by bearded Spanish soldiers)

The most extensive treatment of the possible origin of the word comes from [this Chilean site on hard-to-find etymologies](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?bizarro), which says in part:

> El origen del español *bizarro* lo
>   ha estudiado Corominas en su *Diccionario Crítico
>   Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico* (DCECH)
>   en un artículo muy bien documentado con gran
>   profusión de datos históricos y
>   lingüísticos y que no deja lugar a dudas sobre su
>   origen italiano: Viene del término *bizzarro*
>   "iracundo", "furioso", "fogoso", que, a su vez, **deriva de *bizza*
>   "ira instantánea", "rabieta", término éste
>   ya de origen incierto**.

Loosely translated, that paragraph says that the origin of the Spanish word *bizarro* was studied by Corominas in his *Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico* in a very well-documented article with a great profusion of historical and linguistic data, and that it leaves **no room for doubt regarding the Italian origin**.  However, the Italian word *bizza* (meaning quick anger) which the Italian word *bizzarro* in turn derives from is itself of uncertain further origin.

I should point out that earlier in the French citation, Littré disregards the *bizza* theory on the grounds that *-arro* isn’t an Italian suffix.

They then continue with this, addressing the Basque myth:

> El pretendido origen vasco lo analiza Corominas desde sus comienzos y
>   le hace un seguimiento esclarecedor. Parece ser que el primero en
>   sugerirlo fue Baltasar de Echaue, en su obra *Discursos de la
>   antigüedad de la lengua cántabra bascongada*
>   (1607), donde la hacía derivar de "*viçarra*,
>   hombre de barba o pelo en pecho". Se aceptó esta
>   etimología con rapidez y escaso sentido crítico,
>   especialmente por autores de gustos marcadamente vascófilos,
>   sin reparar en que el euskera *bizarr* significa
>   únicamente "barba".
>
> Tampoco se reparó, y esto parece menos excusable en los 
>   estudios diacrónicos de una lengua, en el hecho incontestable
>   de que en italiano la palabra está en uso continuado desde,
>   por lo menos, el s. XIII (1212), mientras que en español no
>   aparece hasta el último tercio del s. XVI (1569). En vano se
>   la busca en ningún autor medieval -salvo una
>   aparición aislada: en la traducción precisamente de
>   la *Divina Comedia* de Dante hecha por el
>   Marqués de Villena en 1428, lo que habrá que
>   interpretar mejor como una interferencia léxica del italiano-,
>   ni tampoco en los lexicógrafos de los ss. XV y XVI como Alonso
>   Fernández de Palencia (1490), Elio Antonio de Nebrija (1495),
>   Pedro de Alcalá (1505), Cristóbal de las Casas (1570)
>   o Alonso Sánchez de la Ballesta (1587).

The gist of that, and the rest of the article, is that they don’t buy the Basque origin theory one single bit.

The Basque origin theory was seized upon by Basque sympathizers even though the Basque word only means “beard” not “valiant”.  There is also a distinct paucity of medieval evidence for the word in Spanish, appearing uniquely in a translation of Dante, where it was taken for a loanword.  The rest of the article also casts doubt on whether the Italian word first appeared in French or in Spanish.

So although the strongest arguments deny an ultimately Basque origin for *bizarre*, no completely convincing alternate theories for the ultimate origin present themselves either.

That’s because although English *bizarre* comes from Italian *bizzarro* by way of French, we aren’t sure that the Italian *bizzarro* dating from 1212 actually comes from Italian *bizza* (“quick anger”) — plus even if it does, we don’t know where *bizza* comes from, for there the trail grows cold.

---

### In Italian

In a comment Josh61 pointed out what the Italians think of their word *bizzarro*.  Specifically, what Ottorino Pianigiani thought of it in his [*Vocabolario etimologico della lingua italiana*](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottorino_Pianigiani#Vocabolario_etimologico_della_lingua_italiana) of 1907, which I [quote](https://archive.org/stream/vocabolarioetim00piangoog/vocabolarioetim00piangoog_djvu.txt) below (using the original spelling):

> ### biżżarro
>
> Sembra che il primo significato
>   sia stato quello che tuttora remani'nello
>   spanuolo e nel portoghese (bizarro) di
>   Animoso, Baldo, Generoso, Liberale (onde
>   probabilm. il nome propr. di *Pizzarro*) e
>   che tragga dal *basc.* BIZARRA *prode, valoroso*,
>   che si presterebbe anche a spiegare
>   il senso di *facile a infierire, stizzoso,
>   iracondo,* già antico nell’idioma italiano,
>   p. es.
>
> > Lo fiorentino spirito bizzarro
> >      in sè medesmo si volvea co’denti.
> >          (Dante, *Inf.* VIII, 62);
>
> nonché l’altro di *vivo, brioso*. Quello però
>   che non sta in armonia cogli accennati
>   significati è il senso oggi prevalente di
>   Capriccioso, Stravagante, Fantastico, Strano,
>   che domina nel francese (<sub><sup>**BIZARRE**</sup></sub>),
>   e che l’Heise crede spiegare narrando
>   come i francesi del mezzogiorno cosí
>   appellassero gli spagnuoli, perché solit portare
>   lunga *barba*, che in basco se dice <sub><sup>**BIZARRA**</sup></sub>,
>   e siccome gli spagnuoli erano
>   famosi per i loro modi ampollosi e strani
>   cosí l’aggettivo <sub><sup>**BIZARRE**</sup></sub> a poco per volta
>   sarebbe passato al significato di *stravagante*.
>   Invece il Muratori propone il *fr.* <sub><sup>**BIGARRE**</sup></sub>
>   *di colore variegato* da <sub><sup>**BIGARRER**</sup></sub>
>   *cat.* <sub><sup>**BIGARRAR**</sup></sub> *screziare* (che il Menage
>   trae del *lat.* <sub><sup>**BIS**</sup></sub> e <sub><sup>**VARIÀRE**</sup></sub>, altri da <sub><sup>**BIS**</sup></sub>
>   e *fr.* <sub><sup>**CARRÉ**</sup></sub> *quadrato*, quasi *fatto a quadri*)
>   lo che sarebbe in certo modo avvalorato
>   dall’applicazione frequente che se fa della
>   voce <sub><sup>**BIZARRO**</sup></sub> alle stoffe di colori stavaganti,
>   d’done poi sarebbe passata a designare
>   il carattere stravagante di una persona.
>   Ma forse, secondo che si applia a
>   persona o a cosa, è voce distinta e di varia
>   origine, quantunque suoni ugualmente.
>   Altri inoltre partendo dal *stizzoso*,
>   ha creduto trovare spiegazione in
>   <sub><sup>**BIZZA**</sup></sub> con la terminazione germanica <sub><sup>**ÀRDO**</sup></sub>
>   cambiato in <sub><sup>**ÀRRO**</sup></sub>, e si è pensato perfino
>   al *pers.* <sub><sup>**BIZAR**</sup></sub> *sdegnarsi*, che farebbe al
>   bisogno se avvese anelli di congiunzione
>   nelle lingue euopee. Il Caix finalmente
>   con piú artificio lo vorebbe contratto da
>   <sub><sup>**REBIDIÀRIO**</sup></sub>, formato de <sub><sup>**REBÍDIO**</sup></sub> usato in
>   antico per *aribrtrio* (*cfr. Ghiribizzo*).
>
> Deriv. *Biżżarraménte; Biżżaría; Imbiżżarriri; Sbiżżarrsírsi.*

The summary is that they aren’t sure either, but they
think the existing Spanish and Portuguese sense of the word is
the original Italian sense, too, despite the “extravagant” sense it 
has taken on in recent years, citing Dante having used it in this way.

They then recount the opinions of various scholars on 
various possible origins, ranging from the strange and 
bombastic ways of Spaniards to mottled colors of paintings
leading to persons of eccentric character, and the even more
whimsical theories.

They also suggest a possible connection with a Germanic word for being angry,
and theorize that the Germanic *-ardo* suffix became *-arro*.  Regarding *bizza* they say:

> ### bíżża
>
> La Crusca ritiene che sia forma
>   varia ed intensiva di <sub><sup>**ÍZZA**</sup></sub> (v. q. voce), ma
>   invece pare che possa trarsi assai bene
>   dall’ *a. a. ted.* <sub><sup>**BIZZAN**</sup></sub> =
>   *mod.* <sub><sup>**BEISSEN**</sup></sub> pungere
>   e propr. *mordere:* onde ne verrebbe il
>   significato di *puntiglio* (v. *Biscia*). — Collera,
>   Stizza, nella quale per lo piú è del
>   capriccioso, simile a quella di un cavallo
>   punto da’ tafani, e dicesi piú specialmente
>   dei bambini e delle donne che si adirano
>   e strillano per cose da nulla.
>
> Deriv. *Biżżóso*.

Which mentions the connection to Proto-Germanic *bizzan*, 
meaning to sting or bite, or pique. It seems to means 
capricious anger like a horse stung/bitten  by a fly.

### Pizza and Pizarro

One commenter thought that the current pronunciation of *bizarre* in French or English or *bizarro* in Spanish doesn’t sound anything like the Italian sound heard in *pizza*, and so disbelieves the proposed Italian origin.  As Janus rightly points out in comments, there is no spelling conflict 
between the Italian and the Spanish versions, since [when Spanish
imported it, its *z* would have been  /d͡z/ anyway](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol), as this diagram from the referenced article shows:

[image: esquema del reajuste de las sibilantes del español medieval]

One should probably also mention the surname of [Francisco *Pizarro*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Pizarro), the Spanish conquistador of the Incan Empire, as well as the Spanish words *pizzara, pizarrón*  meaning chalk and chalkboard. Although the surname might be a case of nominative determinism if it was equated with *bizarro* brave, apparently the chalky words’ origin is also debated.  The [RAE says](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=pizarra) only that  *pizarra* is of inconclusive origin.

Inconclusive, but what are the theories? In the website [Recursos Didácticos Docencia Universitaria](https://recursosdidacticosdocenciauniversitaria.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/el-pizarron-la-pizarra/) they write:

> Antiguamente trozos de pizarras (tipo de piedra) se usaban de forma individual y en dimensiones pequeñas, por lo que se ideo utilizar la pared pintada directamente o sobre madera en mayor dimensión, pero conservando su nombre de pizarra o pizarrón dado su nueva extensión.Los primeros datos sobre el empleo del pizarrón datan del siglo XVIII.
>
> La palabra pizarrón proviene de “pizarra”, que es una roca de grano muy fino de color negro azulado que se puedes dividir fácilmente en hojas planas. Pizarra tiene su origen en el latín “fissus”, que significa hendido, abierto. Otros autores afirman que su origen es vasco de la palabra “pizarra”.

So here again we have a dispute about whether a very similar word derives from Basque  or from another language, in this case Latin *fissus*, which I myself have trouble believing but stranger thing have happened.

Comment: It's curious that while the *strongest arguments deny an ultimately Basque origin* and *not Basque but Italian* why don't the esteemed OED scholars come to that same conclusion or at least mention it?

Comment: @Jim Perhaps because they didn’t consult the Iberian lexicographers mentioned in the Chilean article. If you have better evidence, present it. It is an injustice to attempt to close an honest question about something that is **not** a matter of General Reference, but rather one that would score you a klaxon during the General Ignorance round on the BBC’s *QI*. The purported Basque origin is nonsense, but it is frequently repeated.

Comment: No, I don't.  I'm just saying that if this stuff can be found online by the likes of you or me in a matter of minutes then the OED researchers should know all that and yet they didn't include any of it.

Comment: @Jim - I think you misunderstand the depth of tchrist's knowledge here. He didn't just *find this stuff online*. He *majored* in 'this stuff' *in Spain*. It's literally not what the likes of you and me can find.

Comment: @medica- I'm not looking to start a fight, just an interesting discussion.  I've seen tchrist's posts over the years and appreciate the depth of his knowledge.  In this post though, apart from the OED entry, the post links the RAE, Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, Littré, About World Languages, and a Chilean site on hard-to-find etymologies- all online. The post mostly quotes, translates and/or summarizes information from those sites. For example, I don't think this post is like some of John Lawler's, where he cites his own work on umich for example.

Comment: @Jim An English monoglot wouldn't be able to read the French and Spanish originals, and probably would not find them to start with, so it cannot be General Reference. I don't own the DCECH, but it sounds like the work by Corominas on the word is dispositive for refuting a Basque origin. I might be able to dig it up if you really need it.

Comment: I'm not arguing about the GR aspect. I've withdrawn my close vote.  I'm wondering why OED didn't draw the same conclusions you've drawn. (Which you've addressed in a comment above.  So I guess we've come full circle, and I'll shut up now ;-)).

Comment: @Jim The most likely answer, but hardly the only one, is that that particular OED entry dates from before Corominas's work in the 80s, and they didn't do the legwork themselves. The OED is often like that: their trace often dead-ends once they locate an origen one or two steps outside English.

Comment: There IS, in fact, a perfectly reasonable argument for the Basque (bearded) explanation (as opposed to the Italian). If you know how to pronounce the It. word "pizza", the Fr. and Eng. "bizarre" (from "bizzarro")seems less likely to be related. And, as for "bearded" transmogrifying into "strange/odd/weird" - may I suggest the propensity of little old ladies of the region to have impressive chin whiskers. (Bizarre, right?)

Comment: @tchrist - http://www.etimo.it/?term=bizza. Here they make 2 assumptions: from IZZA, or, most likely, from old german BIZZAN, to sting or bite.

Comment: A. Rey says in Dict. hist. L. Fr.; borrowed from It. "bizzaro" as in "coléreux" then "extravagant", itself of disputed origin: neither of Spanish which is taken from Italian and from which origins "brave" in Fr 16th, nor from basque bizar "barbe", which would relate to an energetic man by meton. Then goes on to say in Fr. the form wasn't immediately fixed and "bigarre" lived alongside "bizarre" etc. Paraphrasing here, please see actual work. Thank you.

Comment: @Josh61 [Their own explanation for *bizzarro*](http://www.etimo.it/?cmd=id&id=2356&md=34fa8d6513c7a97e4dda511106d80f4f) isn’t too sure either, although they at least postulate a possible Germanic *-ardo* suffix giving way to the otherwise alien *-arro* one.

Comment: @Oldbag That’s not really an argument if you look more closely at it. In fact, I’d rather think it was another argument against the Basque origin. The Italian ⟨zz⟩ here represents [d͡zː] (neither French nor Spanish had preserved consonant length, so that’s only relevant for Italian); the Basque ⟨z⟩ represents [s], as opposed to ⟨s⟩ which represents [s̺]. Spanish in the 1560s had a phoneme /d͡z/ just like Italian, but unlike Basque; this was written ⟨z⟩. Normal /s/ was [s̺] in Spanish, as in Basque. French had already lost /d͡z/ by this time and had only /s z/ left. [cont’d-->]

Comment: [-->cont’d] Around 1600, Spanish /d͡z/ merged with unvoiced /t͡s/ ⟨ç⟩, which was then ‘unstopped’ to /s/, so in the first half of the 17th century, Spanish also contrasted laminal /s/ [s] ⟨z, ç⟩ with apical /s̺/ [s̺] ⟨s⟩. This probably influenced the etymology proposed in 1607, when Spanish _bizarro_ [biˈ(t)saro] matched Basque _bizarr_ [biˈsar] almost perfectly. But half a century or more earlier when the word was borrowed, it was [biˈd͡zaro], which fits the Italian, but not the Basque. In fact, a borrowing from Italian had 300 years to happen, while one from Basque had only [cont’d-->]

Comment: [-->cont’d] perhaps 50 or 60 years before Spanish /s/ [s] ⟨z, ç⟩ started moving towards [θ] and differing again from Basque [s].

Comment: @Janus Indeed. One wonders how Pizarro would have pronounced his own surname. The diagram above suggests the s₂ version, which would not have been any existing English sibilant. There are still a lot of “odd” sibilants around Iberia, which an Anglophone monoglot will find don’t quite fit into said Anglophone’s expected scheme of *s* vs. *sh* vs. *th* (plus the voiced versions where those occur allophonically.